# perl Imager::File::PNG. Why does the install fail to find my libpng installed via MacPorts?

Tags: perl, macports, libpng

I have installed libpng via MacPorts. Check.
I have install Imager via cpan install. During the install it fails to find the path to my libpng which I installed via MacPorts without any issues.

This is the contents of `/usr/local/lib`:

```
libpng.3.dylib*
libpng.3.dylib.dSYM/
libpng12.0.dylib*
libpng12.0.dylib.dSYM/
libpng12.a
libpng12.la*
libpng14.14.dylib*
libpng14.14.dylib.dSYM/
libpng14.a
libpng14.la*
libpng15.15.dylib*
libpng15.15.dylib.dSYM/
libpng15.a
libpng15.la*
```

What have I missed?

UPDATE
- I am install on MacBook running Maverick (10.9.3)
- Prior to Maverick installation my code worked fine

Here is a blow by blow of my cpan install effort

```
cpan[1]> force install Imager::File::PNG
Reading '/Users/turner/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Tue, 24 Jun 2014 13:17:02 GMT
Running install for module 'Imager::File::PNG'
Checksum for /Users/turner/.cpan/sources/authors/id/T/TO/TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.89.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /Users/turner/.cpan/build for sizes
............................................................................DONE
Configuring T/TO/TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.89.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
PNG: building independently
PNG: Found via pkg-config libpng
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png15'
PNG: v1.6: includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png16'
PNG: v1.5: includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png15'
PNG: v1.4: includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png14'
PNG: v1.2: includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png12'
PNG: v1.0: includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: base (+libz): includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png', 'z'
PNG: v1.6 (+libz): includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png16', 'z'
PNG: v1.5 (+libz): includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png15', 'z'
PNG: v1.4 (+libz): includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png14', 'z'
PNG: v1.2 (+libz): includes found - libraries found
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png12', 'z'
PNG: v1.0 (+libz): includes not found - libraries not found
PNG: Checking if the compiler can find them on its own
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -lpng
PNG: Test code failed: Can't link/include 'png.h', 'stdio.h', 'png'
OS unsupported: PNG libraries or headers not found
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
  TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.89.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 TONYC/Imager-File-PNG-0.89.tar.gz            : writemakefile NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 512
```

Comment: show the actual error?

Comment: Building from *-0.89.tar.gz ?  That's pretty old (July 1996) and doesn't supply any of the versions 1.0 through 1.6 that you searched for.